# WordPress Rewrite : Dynamic URL Parsing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url-rewriting

On a WordPress based site, I'm trying to do something like Twitter or Facebook's username URL suffix. Member URLs would be something like:

```
domain.com/username
```

However, we also have custom pages that are hosted on the same domain root. Example of the URLs are:

```
domain.com/contact
domain.com/support
domain.com/register
domain.com/login
```

I have considered adding custom rules for each user by binding WordPress' WP_Rewrite to the `user_register` action but I learned that this would be stored in the `options` table under the `rewrite_rules` column, the value of which is stored in `longtext`. I'm concerned with the scalability of this approach and possible drawbacks against future DB performance.

Basically, we first have to check if the request made is of a valid existing username, and if not, check if it's a valid WordPress post or page, and if not, redirect to the 404 page.

Note that we don't want our own pages to have a prefix ( e.g. domain.com/p/contact ).

How do I go about solving this one?

Thank you very much.